# Template overriding in custom npm-modules in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In order to have a common setup in most of my Apostrophe projects, I plan on building some custom npm-modules to bundle them and add them to my projects. Some of the features I would like to do in them, appart from adding widgets and backend functionality, is editing official apostrophe modules' setup (e.g., setting up default page types for `apostrophe-pages`) and overriding nunjuck blocks and/or templates.

Both things can easily be overwritten on a project-level configuration with Apostrophe's implicit subclassing mechanism, so my goal of sharing a common base setup for different projects could be achieved with a custom boilerplate, although I would lose the ability of upgrading my defaults by releasing new versions of my node modules.

All in all, I was thinking in a Maven-style dependency hierarchy like this:

`Apostrophe npm modules <- custom npm modules <- project modules`

Coming form a Java and Maven based CMS, I understand I will need to change my way of thinking in many things, so: is what I'm trying to do possible and does it make sense in the Apostrophe world? What would be "The Apostrophe Way" to achieve something like this? Do I need to create a custom npm module to with the moog option `improve` for each module I want to extend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the `npm_modules` directory, apostrophe will scaffold out base modules first and modules that extend those modules second, meaning your custom npm modules will follow the same inheritance chain as the official apostrophe modules. You can override them the same way you would any other apostrophe module.

`meta module (apostrophe-pieces) > custom-pieces (piece extension, custom npm module) > custom-pieces (project-level overrides)`

You would just selectively override files and methods in `lib/modules/` the same way you'd override parts of `apostrophe-blog`, like `lib/modules/custom-pieces/views/widget.html`

Am I correctly understanding the way you want to override things?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So I could have a module `@acme/apostrophe-pages´ extending `apostrophe-pages` and including the `default.html` and, in my actual project, I would need to reference both modules in`àpp.js`?

What about overriding the views in the root `views` folder? (Yes, I'm still trying to figure out all the layout, outerlayout and outerlayoutbase hierarchy, sorry!)

Comment: To interact with a core module like `apostrophe-pages` you DO want to create improvement modules, which could alter base settings or provide new templates. These would have their own namespace (@acme/acme-apostrophe-pages). Then you would override them at project level by overriding the original core module (lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/layout.html). See an example of an official improve module targeting apostrophe-pages https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-personas/blob/fd7b61a6a6ef170ac3d14d072df0f9f8d3b4603b/lib/modules/apostrophe-personas-pages/index.js

Comment: Ok, so rather than _extending_ the base module and using the child one, I need to _improve_ it so that the changes are applied directly to the base module and all their children. Great example!